# MVC calling stored procedure is not updating UI

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to update my inventory database quantity. When I clicked on the UI, I can debug through my code and everything looks OK. But the web UI is still showing the old data (old quantity). I tried to refresh and navigate back and forth. But as long as the current connection is there, the data is not updating. If I stop debugging and look into the database file, all data are up to date. If I start my app again, now all data are updated. Is there anything missing when I call the stored procedure?

I tried to call DBContext.SaveChanges(); But with or without it, the behavior is the same.

```
    public bool POFiled(long POId)
    {
        DBContext.PurchaseOrderFiled(POId);
        DBContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

PurchaseOrderFiled is the name of the stored procedure.

Access: Public

Name: PurchaseOrderFiled

Return Type: None

Stored Procedure Name: uspPurchaseOrderFiled

Thanks!

Comment: That's because your entity query has the old data. It could be better to call the action again or work with an async call.

Comment: You're saying that your web app doesn't show whats in the database. You need to post some code that reads that data back and displays it. The code you've posted saves changes. It doesn't read anything back or display it.

Comment: Thanks! I figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a comment which will give someone else a clue if they have the same issue

Comment: Just as Murat said. The data is not updated in this thread. I need to get it from other threads.